# Show dialog box before someone can sort a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

1. I have a column with numbers (results from a query).
2. The numbers won't add unless I format it as number (Format menu > Number > Number).
3. After formatting them as numbers, i get the total. However, the users of the spreadsheet doesn't know or is forgetting the step to format the numbers as number.
4. The only action from them to trigger this is when sorting col2 using row1:col2
5. I'm thinking of a solution to show a dialog box that says "Please Format col 2 as numbers by going to Format menu > Number > Number"
6. I've tried adding onEdit for row1:col2 but this doesn't work when the use for sorting (only works when editing the cell value).

Needed help to:
Show dialog box when **col2** isn't in number format before they can sort it using header in **E85**.

Tried:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = "REPORTS (AUTO)";
var row = e.range.getRow();
if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'E85' && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ss){
<show dialog box code here...>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sorting does not fire the `onEdit` trigger, but it does fire the [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onChange` trigger

- Thereby, `onChange` features the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `changeType`
- Sorting a sheet results in the `changeType` `OTHER`

Now you can write a function as following:

```js
function bindMeToAnOnChangeTrigger(e){
  if(e.changeType=="OTHER"){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Please go to Format menu > Number > Number");
  }
}
```

- Note that you need to manualy bind the function `bindMeToAnOnChangeTrigger(e)` to an installable `onEdit` trigger, by going on `Edit->Current Project's triggers->New trigger`
- Note that certain other `onCahnge` events of type `OTHER` might also fire the trigger, so you might want to implement additional criteria to verify eith ther user shall be alerted.

UPDATE

If you want to implement an additoinal condition checking for cell formatting before showing the alert, you can use [getNumberFormats()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumberformats):

```js
function bindMeToAnOnChangeTrigger(e){
  if(e.changeType=="OTHER"){
    var sheetName = "REPORTS (AUTO)";
    var range = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange("A2:A20");
    var formats = range.getNumberFormats().flat();
    Logger.log(formats);
    //Please set here your desired number format
    var desiredFormat = "0.###############"
    for(var i = 0; i < formats.length; i++){
      if(formats[i] != desiredFormat){
        return;
      }
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I just need a little help for the criteria. What can I do to check if range `A2:A20` is in a number format so the `bindMeToAnOnChangeTrigger` won't be called? Also, the condition I have is `e.range.getA1Notation() === 'E85'` but when I sort using F85 and others, it still shows the message.

Comment: As for retrieving the formats - you can use [getNumberFormats](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumberformats) - see my updated answer. As for `e.range.getA1Notation()` - unfortunately `e.range` is not a valid event object for onChange triggers. Maybe you have some other criteria that does not involve retrieving `e.range` or `e.value`?

Comment: Thanks for the update. AS for the e.range, the criteria is when E85 was the cell that was sorted and not F85 or other headers...

Comment: How do you sort by header? Do you have a dropdown menu in row 85?